# How to symfony 1.4 parse filter Odata V2?

Tags: odata, render, symfony-1.4

I are having a problem about the API. I working on framwork Symfony 1.4 and plugin Igniteui with Filter OData V2. I want to ask Symfony 1.4 have plugin or solution for Filter OData V2? Thanks.

Url Filter: callback=jQuery19101818354631625243_1458209143729&$filter=indexof(tolower(pname),'3242342') ge 0 and indexof(tolower(palias),'23423424') ge 0 and indexof(tolower(plang),'34534535') ge 0 and indexof(tolower(pprice),'345345') ge 0&pageindex=0&pagesize=25&_=1458209143735

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand you. Do you need to know if Symfony 1.4 has a plugin or a built-in solution to parse OData?

Comment: Yes, I need a solution to parse URL  OData with Symfony 1.4.

Comment: Sorry, but there isn't. I only found one tool for PHP: https://odataphp.codeplex.com/ but according to comments on the site, it seems that it doesn't work very well.